# How to set intent-filter to make my app into default gallery on android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

To get qualification to be default gallery app, I set `intent-filter` in my app's manifest file.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

However, I could not find my app at the list shown up when I touched the gallery icon of the default camera app. What do I have to do more?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons only the android user can declare an app as a **default** for xxxx.

You can declare that your app is capable to handle some intent and then the user can decide in the chooser if this should become the default.

you have to look into the sourcecode of the camera app to find out which intent it uses.

on my android-4.2 this undocumented action opens the gallery

```
            <!-- OpenCamera AlmalenceGUI.openExternalGallery() uses 
                 undocumented action="com.android.camera.action.REVIEW" 
                 which in my android-4.2.2 opens the gallery in 
                 swipe mode. -->
            <action android:name="com.android.camera.action.REVIEW" />
```

But this may be different (or even impossible) in other android versions

If the camera (and other apps) use standard intents you can analyse them using https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept (also available in g**e-playstore). but i am afraid your use-case is neither standard nor interceptable